# How to find the real download URL

Tags: wget

I need to download the 64-bit Linux tar file from this webpage:

```
https://www.niehs.nih.gov/research/resources/software/biostatistics/art/index.cfm
```

The 64-bit Linux URL appears to be:

```
https://www.niehs.nih.gov/research/resources/assets/docs/artbinmountrainier2016.06.05linux64.tgz
```

However, wget just downloads something that looks like javascript.
How to find the real URL?

Comment: use the --referer flag with the first link as argument.